# Getting selected items as array of values

Tags: javascript

I've the below code that is having `multiselect` dropdown:

```html
<html>
    <head><title>Hello</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/Semantic-UI-CSS-master/semantic.min.css">
        <script src="/static/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/Semantic-UI-CSS-master/semantic.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <select name="skills" id="skills-select" multiple="" class="ui fluid dropdown">
            <option value="">Skills</option>
            <option value="angular">Angular</option>
            <option value="css">CSS</option>
            <option value="design">Graphic Design</option>
        </select>
    <script>
            $('#skills-select').dropdown();
        </script>

    <button class="ui button" id="go">
      <i class="play icon"></i>
    </button>

    <script>
      $("#go" ).click(function() {
        var x = $('#skills-select :selected').text();
        console.log(x)
      });
    </script>

        </body>
</html>
```

How I read the values of `selected` options in the drop down list as array.
Example, if I selected both `css` and `angular` from the list above, I want to have the output at:
`x = ["css", "angular"]`

Comment: What research have you done into the issue and what attempts have you made based on that research?

Comment: That should be work....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So simple in pure JS:

```js
const getVals      = document.getElementById('get-values')
  ,   skillsSelect = document.getElementById('skills-select')
  ;
getVals.onclick =_=>
  {
  let choosed = [...skillsSelect.selectedOptions].map(e=>e.value)
  console.clear()
  console.log( choosed )
  }
```

```html
<select id="skills-select" multiple >
  <option value="one"     >Skills        </option>
  <option value="angular" >Angular       </option>
  <option value="css"     >CSS           </option>
  <option value="design"  >Graphic Design</option>
</select>

<button id="get-values">getVals </button>
```

Comment: Thanks, what is the equivalent pure JS of `$('#skills-select').dropdown();`

Comment: @HasanAYousef a lot of code. why this question? the only tag you mention is javascript, and no other!

Comment: As you suggested using the pure JS code as an answer, the only remaining jQuery in my code is the one I shown, so thought to make all my code pure JSconly.

Comment: @HasanAYousef well, but there is no `.dropDown()` method in jQuery ...

Comment: It locks it had been added by `semantic` framework, I replaced it by `document.querySelector('#get-values').dropdown();`

Comment: @HasanAYousef Can we have our cake and eat it too?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `val()` method of jQuery instead of getting the `text()` and use `$('#skills-select')` instead of `$('#skills-select :selected')`.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head><title>Hello</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/Semantic-UI-CSS-master/semantic.min.css">
        <script src="/static/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/Semantic-UI-CSS-master/semantic.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <select name="skills" id="skills-select" multiple="" class="ui fluid dropdown">
            <option value="">Skills</option>
            <option value="angular">Angular</option>
            <option value="css">CSS</option>
            <option value="design">Graphic Design</option>
        </select>

    <button class="ui button" id="go">
      <i class="play icon"></i>
    </button>

    <script>
      $("#go" ).click(function() {
        var x = $('#skills-select').val();
        console.log(x)
      });
    </script>

        </body>
</html>
```